# How do I set up this checkbox formula in google sheets? I'm getting #N/A error

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of players in my league and next to each name is a checkbox to show if they are active or not.  I set up a formula that checks each of the 12 weeks of game play to see if a player participated.  If they did participate in any of the 12 weeks, I want the checkbox to be ticked so that their stats get displayed on the stats tab.  I'm getting a lot of this and it's displaying `#N/A`:

ErrorDid not find value 'prduke11' in MATCH evaluation.
Invalid: This cell's contents violate its validation rule

When player is active, the checkbox is ticked like it should be.  My formula is below (I'm using a nested IF formula but have tried writing it with IFS and got similar results) (`$B18` is the player in the list and the formula repeats only changing the Week tab [ex: `Week1!`, `Week2!`, etc] it is searching:

```
=IF(MATCH($B18,Week1!$B$10:$B,0),TRUE,IF(MATCH($B18,Week2!$B$10:$B,0),TRUE,IF(MATCH($B18,Week3!$B$10:$B,0),TRUE,IF(MATCH($B18,Week4!$B$10:$B,0),TRUE,IF(MATCH($B18,Week5!$B$10:$B,0),TRUE,IF(MATCH($B18,Week6!$B$10:$B,0),TRUE,IF(MATCH($B18,Week7!$B$10:$B,0),TRUE,IF(MATCH($B18,Week8!$B$10:$B,0),TRUE,IF(MATCH($B18,Week9!$B$10:$B,0),TRUE,IF(MATCH($B18,Week10!$B$10:$B,0),TRUE,IF(MATCH($B18,Week11!$B$10:$B,0),TRUE,IF(MATCH($B18,Week12!$B$10:$B,0),TRUE,FALSE))))))))))))
```

Comment: Welcome. Please share a link to the sheet.

Comment: @pjmg please don't add breaklines to spreadsheet formulas on questions if that was not the intention of the OP because the low formula readability usually is part of the underlying problem. Instead consider to point the OP to a resource about how to write good formulas or about *code smells* in spreadsheets, or even better, answer the question and include a brief explanation about how breaklines are added to formulas and how they help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something along these lines:

```
=((countif($b18,Week1!$b$10:$b) + countif($b18,Week2!$b$10:$b) + ... ) = 12)
```

Good luck!